# Есть 2 TimerTask подскажите как их остановить на время

Tags: java, android

Есть 2 TimerTask подскажите как их остановить на время.

Нужно сделать 2 запроса. Один каждые 15 сек. другой каждые 30.

Можно ли как то их на паузу поставить, а после того как в Broadcast придет ответ то продолжить работу в том или ином TimerTask

нужно последовательно сделать 2 запроса get в TimerTask, а то они конфликтуют.

Comment: Изучите многопоточность и вопросы пропадут.

Comment: Через RxJava всё это делается без проблем

Comment: Вы наверное не поняли. Я запускаю 3 таймера. 1 работае каждые 5 сек. след 10 след 15.  Бывает так что конфликт происходит. Так как сервер медленный и задержка перед получением может быть аж в 4 сек. Для этого я хотел узнать как остановить 2 и 3 потоки пока выполняется 1. после 2 после 3 и т.д. по кругу